# How to genrate excel file on azure storage using c# console application?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-scheduler

I have a console application which is fire some SQL queries on azure SQL and data will transfer into excel file. This is working fine on my local computer.
Issue
But I want host this .exe on azure service as scheduler. That time I realize, how to keep my generated file excel on azure.

```js
public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string excelFilename)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                {
                    WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
                }
                Trace.WriteLine("Successfully created: " + excelFilename);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In above code, What I need to pass "excelFilename"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In above code, What I need to pass "excelFilename"?

In Azure, I suggest save the excel file to Azure Blob Storage. Based on your code, you could create a new excel which hosted in memory stream. After wrote data to this excel file, we can upload the memory stream to Blob Storage. Code below is for your reference.

```
public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
        }
        //You need to create a storage account and put your azure storage connection string in following place
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("put your azure storage connection string here");         
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("excelfilecontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        ms.Position = 0;
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use upper method, you just need to place the file name in the second parameter.

```
CreateExcelDocument(ds, "abc.xlsx");
```

After that, a file named abc.xlsx will be created in excelfilecontainer of your Blob Storage. You could view or download it from Azure Storage Explorer or Azure Storage Client Library.

[image]

> And If excel sheet or dataset have more than one. Then how to add new sheet ?

We also could read the blob data to a memory stream. Then we can open a SpreadsheetDocument based this stream. After add a new sheet. We need to save this stream back to blob storage. Here is the sample code.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage connection string");
// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("excelfilecontainer");
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob.txt"
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("abc.xlsx");

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(memoryStream, false))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, And If excel sheet or dataset have more than one. Then how to add new sheet ?

Comment: I modified my reply based on your comment. If you need more help of how to use SpreadsheetDocument, I suggest you post a new question with an [openxml-sdk] tag. You will get more professional help there. If your issue is solved, I suggest you mark helpful reply as answer. A thread which has been marked will be easily searched. It will help other community members who encounter similar issues.